# With angularfire2, how to write new key generated as an field child

Tags: angular, key, push, angularfire2

I'm trying to write the new key generated on push inside an child field.

Is it possible to write on the same write transaction?  something like below...

```
const evt = this.angularfire2Service.afDb.list('/path/');
evt.push({
    id : <<<< key generated on push >>>>>
    title: newdata.title,
 }).then( newrec => {
        console.log('chave = ', newrec.key)
});
```

as workaround, I can write as:

```
.then( newrec => {
     console.log('chave = ', e.key);
     this.angularfire2Service.afDb.object('/path/+newrec.key).update({
        id: newrec.key
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using firebase sdk for that.
Indeed, key is already generated when using .push()
i.e.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

Then

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref('/path').push();

ref.set({
    id: ref.key,
    title: newdata.title
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With angularfire2, on your `event.service.ts`, you need to...

```
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable()
export class EventService {
  userKey: string;

  constructor(private _fbApp: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  addEvent(event) {
    // creating key without pushing data
    this.eventKey = this._fbApp.database.ref('/events').push().key;
    // adding the key as a property to the object you will push
    event.uid = this.eventKey;
    // creating child node with same key and pushing data
    this._fbApp.database().ref('/events').child(this.eventKey).set(event);
}
```

In your `event.component.ts`...

```
addEvent({ value, valid }: { value: Event; valid: boolean }) {
  this._eventService.addEvent(value);
  this._router.navigate(['/']);
}
```

Notice the `{value: Event;` in case you have an interface to validate your object.

This code should create a node key right before you are pushing the data, storing that key in a variable, and right away including the key as a property in the object you are pushing to the node. Notice the `.child(this.eventKey)` is using the just created key as the key node.

Hope this helps!!!